# Different way to know the origin of the click, optimizing my tab system

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript, and I've done this code, I just want to be sure that I'm on the right way, would you have done it differently?

What bothers me is especially to have passed parameters to the functions "next" and "updateArrows" to know the origin of the clicks

```
const changeStep = document.querySelectorAll(".step");
const currentPaginate = document.querySelector(".pagination span.active");
const arrows = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow");

for (let arrow of arrows) {
    arrow.addEventListener("click", function () {
        updateArrows(arrow);
    });
}
for (let step of changeStep) {
    step.addEventListener("click", function () {
        next(step);
    });
}

function updateArrows(arrow, currentStep = null, update = true) {
    let nextStep;
    if (currentStep == null) {
        currentStep = document.querySelector(".step.current");
        if (arrow.classList.contains("arrow-bottom")) {
            nextStep = currentStep.nextElementSibling;
        } else {
            nextStep = currentStep.previousElementSibling;
        }
    } else nextStep = document.querySelector(".step.current");
    if (!arrow.classList.contains("impossible")) {
        if (nextStep.dataset.id != 1 && nextStep.dataset.id != 5) {
            arrows.forEach(function (arrow) {
                if (arrow.classList.contains("impossible")) {
                    arrow.classList.remove("impossible");
                }
            });
        } else if (nextStep.dataset.id == 5) {
            if (arrow.previousElementSibling.classList.contains("impossible"))
                arrow.previousElementSibling.classList.remove("impossible");
            arrow.classList.add("impossible");
        } else if (nextStep.dataset.id == 1) {
            if (arrow.nextElementSibling.classList.contains("impossible"))
                arrow.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("impossible");
            arrow.classList.add("impossible");
        }
        if (update == true) next(nextStep, false);
    }
}

function next(step, update = true) {
    if (!step.classList.contains("current")) {
        const currentStep = document.querySelector(".step.current");
        const nextStep = step.dataset.id;
        currentStep.classList.remove("current");
        step.classList.add("current");
        currentPaginate.textContent = "0" + nextStep;
        let arrow;
        if (currentStep.dataset.id < nextStep) {
            arrow = document.querySelector(".arrow-bottom");
        } else {
            arrow = document.querySelector(".arrow-top");
        }
        if (update == true) updateArrows(arrow, currentStep, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this code? Anything not working?

Comment: This looks like a question for [codereview.se]

Comment: No thank you everything is working ! :) just ask for optimize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you mean.
**Yes you are right**. You can do it better...

Instead of passing the parameter arrow you can read from an [event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Event)

```
const changeStep = document.querySelectorAll(".step");
const currentPaginate = document.querySelector(".pagination span.active");
const arrows = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow");

for (let arrow of arrows) arrow.addEventListener("click", updateArrows);

for (let step of changeStep) step.addEventListener("click",  next);


function updateArrows(e, currentStep = null, update = true) {
    let arrow = null
    e.target ? arrow=e.target : arrow=e
    let nextStep;
    if (currentStep == null) {
        currentStep = document.querySelector(".step.current");
        if (arrow.classList.contains("arrow-bottom")) {
            nextStep = currentStep.nextElementSibling;
        } else {
            nextStep = currentStep.previousElementSibling;
        }
    } else nextStep = document.querySelector(".step.current");
    if (!arrow.classList.contains("impossible")) {
        if (nextStep.dataset.id != 1 && nextStep.dataset.id != 5) {
            arrows.forEach(function (arrow) {
                if (arrow.classList.contains("impossible")) {
                    arrow.classList.remove("impossible");
                }
            });
        } else if (nextStep.dataset.id == 5) {
            if (arrow.previousElementSibling.classList.contains("impossible"))
                arrow.previousElementSibling.classList.remove("impossible");
            arrow.classList.add("impossible");
        } else if (nextStep.dataset.id == 1) {
            if (arrow.nextElementSibling.classList.contains("impossible"))
                arrow.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("impossible");
            arrow.classList.add("impossible");
        }
        if (update == true) next(nextStep, false);
    }
}

function next(e, update = true) {
    let step = null
    e.target ? step = e.target : step=e
    if (!step.classList.contains("current")) {
        const currentStep = document.querySelector(".step.current");
        const nextStep = step.dataset.id;
        currentStep.classList.remove("current");
        step.classList.add("current");
        currentPaginate.textContent = "0" + nextStep;
        let arrow;
        if (currentStep.dataset.id < nextStep) {
            arrow = document.querySelector(".arrow-bottom");
        } else {
            arrow = document.querySelector(".arrow-top");
        }
        if (update == true) updateArrows(arrow, currentStep, false);
    }
}
```

This should work, if not please contact me beforehand.

> While activating the eventListener an event object is passed to function and e.target is an element which was clicked in this case.

What I did was crucial because you sometimes call this function from an eventListener and sometimes from a code. If the element has e.target then it's from an eventListener and if not then it's from code.

> Didn't have a chance to test it since I don't have the rest of the code. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you dude that works ! i can now delete the update = true because that was my old way to know where the click was from :)

Comment: (i replaced if update == true by if (e.target != "undefined"))

Comment: You're good. I am glad you learnt something new. To elaborate: e.target is the element that caused the event to be trigerred/in which the event was fired.